# IndentationError on exception handling block

Tags: python, pandas

```
def getidxmax(window_2, Filtered):
    try: bar = window_2[Filtered].idxmax()
        return bar
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan
```

Am calling the above function like this:

```
bar = getidxmax(window_2, Filtered)
```

But am getting error:

```
 File "<algorithm>", line 22
    return bar
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

`line 22` is where the `try:` begins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for try except isn't perfectly correct.

```
def getidxmax(window_2, Filtered):
    try: 
       return (window_2[Filtered]).idxmax()
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan
```

You don't need to create a new variable bar, you can just try and return the result of window_2[Filtered].idmax() and if that fails, np.nan

Answer (score 1):

```
def getidxmax(window_2, Filtered):
    try:
        bar = window_2[Filtered].idxmax()
        return bar
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan
```